# Start iPad application both in landscape and portrait mode

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

Right now when I start my iPad application, if I'm turning my device in landscape mode then my rootConroller automatically turns my table from portrait to landscape mode. The problem is that it does so by animating the transition. Instead I would like the app to start in landscape mode right away. I've also created an image called Default-Landscape.png which is ignored, so I suspect I have to tweak something in the plist file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your orientation to UISupportedInterfaceOrientations in the Info.plist file